# How to launch GEODJANGO to heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, web-deployment, postgis, geodjango

I don't know why I am having some issues with this heroku. Non-Geo app seems to work with no problem.

I have a Geodjango application with the postgres psql creation of postgis and it runs perfect on my computer(local development).

what is the precess to getting my application to production with heroku, and using the geodjango framework?

is there anything that is extra setup from a normal postgres application?

please any help would be amazing,
thanks...
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

No, there should not be any extra step for heroku, extensions are enabled by default.

The docs regarding PostGIS on heroku are found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-extensions-postgis-full-text-search#postgis:

> Currently, PostGIS can only be used on Production tier Heroku Postgres plans and on hobby plans with Postgres version 9.4 and above.
>
> ...
>
> PostGIS support on Heroku Postgres is in beta and is subject to change
>   in the future.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! But, to further my question.... When using the layer mapping feature "LayerMapping" from the GeoDjango Tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/, how to get it to work within heroku?  Or Do i have to connect to the DB provided from aws through Heroku and run the SHP file local?

Comment: This project is gift for a college, providing them a interactive map of the campus.  ALL of the help means so much!